# Можно ли настроить Samba на отдачу данных из кеша, если отвалился Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, samba

Регулярно отваливается Active Directory. Хочу установить и настроить Самбу, чтобы решить эту проблему: если отвалился Active Directory, она будет брать данные из своего кеша.

Можно ли так сделать в принципе? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Гуглите: SAMBA резервный контроллер домена Active Directory.
Например, вот [неплохая статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/450572/). И конечно классические ресурсы по самбе.
[Раз](http://www.samba4.ru/) и [два](https://smb-conf.ru/).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Извините, а что вам  гугле выдал, что вы  не смогли дать развёрнутый ответ?